# Using Powershell + regex to change files containing certain characters to read-only

Tags: regex, powershell

I would like to use Powershell and regex to periodically scan a specific folder on my server and change the attributes of matching files to read-only.

I would like to match only filenames where the last 2 characters before the extension is a digit between 00-89, and then make those files read-only.

Example:

```
213filename00.pdf  --> will match

filename55.msg  --> will match

AAfilename99.pdf  --> will not match
```

There will always be 2 digits before the extension on every file.

I know how to change the attribute of the files using Powershell, and I can get the listing of files in the directory with Get-ChildItem, but I am a regex noob and I have no idea how to filter the result of gci to only match the last 2 digits before the extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp" -File |
    Where-Object BaseName -like "*[0-8][0-9]"
```

1. List files in `C:\temp`
2. Filter these down to those whose filename (no extension) ends in 00-89

Comment: This worked thanks, I ended up using the following command in a script: gci -Path c:\Test,c:\Test2,C:\Test3 -File -Recurse | Where-Object Basename -like "*[0-8][0-9]" | Set-ItemProperty -name IsReadOnly -Value $true, which is called from Task Scheduler every 15 minutes.